# How to I parse pdf from url to text in ObjectiveC?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, pdf

I am trying to fetch the pdf-data from a URL and then parse it into a NSString in an iOS-app.

Libraries like FastPdfKit fetches the information and then displays it in a new modal viewcontroller which is not what I want. It should rather be loaded and parsed in the same viewcontroller.

When trying to parse it with Quartz as shown here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html

I don't get any callback what so ever even though the page count is 1 as it should be.

So how can I do this in a single viewcontroller?
Thanks :D

Code tried:

```
static void
op_MP (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info)
{
    const char *name;

    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;

    printf("MP /%s\n", name);
}

static void
op_DP (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info)
{
    const char *name;

    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;

    printf("MP /%s\n", name);
}

static void
op_BMC (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info)
{
    const char *name;

    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;

    printf("MP /%s\n", name);
}
static void
op_BDC (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info)
{
    const char *name;

    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;

    printf("MP /%s\n", name);
}
static void
op_EMC (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info)
{
    const char *name;

    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;

    printf("MP /%s\n", name);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGPDFOperatorTableRef myTable;

    myTable = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate();

    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "MP", &op_MP);
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "DP", &op_DP);
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "BMC", &op_BMC);
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "BDC", &op_BDC);
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "EMC", &op_EMC);

    CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument;
    CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("lel.pdf"), NULL, NULL);

    myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);

    int k;
    CGPDFPageRef myPage;
    CGPDFScannerRef myScanner;
    CGPDFContentStreamRef myContentStream;

    int numOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages (myDocument);// 1
    NSLog(@"%i", numOfPages);
    for (k = 0; k < numOfPages; k++) {
        myPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (myDocument, k + 1 );// 2
        myContentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage (myPage);// 3
        myScanner = CGPDFScannerCreate (myContentStream, myTable, NULL);// 4
        CGPDFScannerScan (myScanner);// 5
        CGPDFPageRelease (myPage);// 6
        CGPDFScannerRelease (myScanner);// 7
        CGPDFContentStreamRelease (myContentStream);// 8
    }
    CGPDFOperatorTableRelease(myTable);

}
```

When trying to use pdf2iPhone by ZachRon I get this error:

http://gyazo.com/52c87cc88a397a64cdbb015113c201c6

ViewController.m:

```
#import "JONViewController.h"
#import "pdf.h"

@interface JONViewController ()

@end

@implementation JONViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"lel" withExtension:@"pdf"];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSString *pdfString = convertPDF(string);
    NSLog(@"%@", pdfString);
}
```

Comment: Show your relevant code

Comment: I agree with Shaggy Frog. FWIW, I've used the above to do PDF scanning and it works just fine, but without your code, we can't help you.

Comment: It looks to me like you're not looking for the correct values on the stack in your callbacks. For example, in the "BDC" operator, you're calling `CGPDFScannerPopName()`, but there's a dictionary on the top of the stack, so `CGPDFScannerPopName ()` is going to fail. You need to call `CGPDFScannerPopDictionary()` first, then call `CGPDFScannerPopName()`.

Answer (score 1):

The PdfIphone code worked for me: https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone

It will parse the Pdf for you and return an NSString with the `converPdf` method.

Comment: It looks awesome, but it is written in C, how do I include it without errors and call the methods :o? Thanks :)

Comment: Link to libz to get it to compile. What I did for calling it was to convert the `convertPdf` method to Objective-C style, not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: I get this error when using libz and calling the method as seen in the question above :/ http://gyazo.com/52c87cc88a397a64cdbb015113c201c6

Comment: Did you add the PdfIphone source directly to your project, or is it in a new project and you're linking to it?

Comment: I drag - dropped it into my project